# Better way of writing a script to avoid boolean error

Tags: powershell

I have written a script and as part of the script I am checking if a job is running and if it is, forcing it to stop:

```
$copyjob = Get-Job -Name DBACopy_QFR1-DBA20_2_QFR3-DBS21_S_Drv_DBA -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($copyjob)
{
    remove-job $copyjob -force   # This job my be causing problems with the backups so we kill it to make sure.
}
```

However, I think what I have written is the cause of this error when the script runs:

> Cannot convert value "System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0

Is there a better way of doing it that doesn't throw up that error, or am I completely incorrect in thinking that this is what is spawning the error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if ($copyjob)
{
}
```

try using

```
if ($copyjob -ne $null)
{
}
```

Comment: Still throwing up the same error. There is always the chance that it isn't that portion of the script.

Comment: Well then I would say write some Write-Output or Write-Host statements in your script and trace which part is throwing the error. You can look at the output and see till what point the execution progresses and where it fails. Something like Write-Output "Getting running jobs to remove" for the above example.

Answer (score 0):

If that is all your code does, you can simplify that:

```
Remove-Job -Name DBACopy_QFR1-DBA20_2_QFR3-DBS21_S_Drv_DBA -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Less code, less chances to fail. You can also pipeline:

```
Get-Job -Name "SomeName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | remove-job -force
```

Comment: If the job with name "DBACopy_QFR1-DBA20_2_QFR3-DBS21_S_Drv_DBA" doesn't exist it would throw error.

Comment: and will continue because of `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` comes from question.

Comment: @autosvet: Makes sense.